# Need to add photo upload to my existing script for mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, image, upload, blob

I need to upload a photo with each record I insert to mySQL.  I already made a basic insert script.  How would I modify my existing script so I can include an image with every record insert.  The images can be of any shape or size.  Very simple.  I simplified the form just for the photo.  Any help would be appreciated.

I made a folder in the root directory for the photos called:  "photos".

```
<?
$order = "INSERT INTO reg_add (connect_date, 
   reg, 
   first_name, 
   last_name)

VALUES

('$_POST[connect_date]', 
     '{$_POST[reg]}nv', 
     '$_POST[first_name]', 
     '$_POST[last_name]')";

$new_image = 'photos/'.basename( $_FILES['image']['name']);
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $new_image)) {
        // The images was uploaded
  } else{
header("location: reg_add_fail_IMAGE.php"); 
}

$result = mysql_query($order);
?>
```

FORM:

```
<form id="form_register" method="POST" action="reg_add.php">

   <input class="req-string bx short" type="text" name="connect_date" id="connect_date">
   <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000">
   <input class="req-string bx long caps" type="text" name="reg" id="reg">
   <input class="req-string bx long" type="text" name="first_name">
   <input class="bx long" type="text" name="last_name">

   Choose a image to upload: <input name="image" type="file">
   <input id="rbSubmit" class="rb2 rbSubmit" type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Hnestly, I don't know where to start.

Comment: Try googling: php file upload. Hint: textareas aren't going to help you upload a file.

Comment: How about [Google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=upload+image+from+html+form+using+php)?  Or that big list of **Related** questions to the right?

Comment: what kind of photo? and is it going to be the same photo for every user that uploads? i see that its on register, are you trying to create a default user image?

Answer (score 0):

First, you cant upload a image using `<textarea>`

**HTML**

```
<form action="savedata.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000" />
    Choose a image to upload: <input name="image" type="file" /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Note it is important that you include `enctype="multipart/form-data` so that the image is sent along with the form.

**PHP**
When a form with FILE is sent to a PHP script the file is stored in a temporary location on the server, and the variable `$_FILE` is available. This variable holds the information about this file, the temporary name and the real name, size and so on.

What you need to do is move the uploaded image to the directory you want it to be placed:

```
// This will be the location for the image
$new_image = 'photos/'.basename( $_FILES['image']['name']);

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $new_image)) {
   // The images was uploaded
} else{
    // The image failed to upload
}
```

Now you can save `$new_image` to database for reference to the image location.

**A couple of things you should consider**

- Check if there is a file with the file name already existing
- If there is a maximum of 1 image per database row, you could name the image using the id from database `INSERT` To do this you need to INSERT the data first, then get last insert id using `$id = mysql_insert_id();` immediately after the INSERT query. then you incorporate this into the variable `$new_image'

Comment: Why is this answer voted down? Isn't it what you were asking for?

Comment: I need to create a blob in mySQL?  Do I call it "new_image"

Comment: oops.  I called it "image".  The upload works.  Now I need to see it.  Trying to figure out how to see it.

Comment: Why do you create a `BLOB` in database if you store the image in the filesystem?

BLOB is used for storing binary data like a file or something, but it is not a good practice to store files in database, they belong in the filesystem

You should create a new `VARCHAR` and store the filename of the image there.